# Want to add no image and image resolution change ability into this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger, blogspot

I am using this script to generate image thumbnail for my readmore hack everything is working fine but the problem is that there is no script to add default image for post without images and the images appears are the one with defualt resolution but i want to change it to max i.e. s1600.

```
function stripTags(s, n) {
    return s.replace(/&lt;.*?&gt;/ig, &quot;&quot;).split(/\s+/).slice(0, n - 1).join(&quot; &quot;)
}
function rm(a) {
    var p = document.getElementById(a);
    imgtag = &quot;&quot;;
    ifrtag = &quot;&quot;;
    ifrsrc = &quot;&quot;;
    ifrtb = -1;
   var video;
   var videoUrl;
   var videoId;
  var service = &quot;&quot;;
  var checkCase = &quot;&quot;;
var thumbnailUrl;
    img = p.getElementsByTagName(&quot;img&quot;);
    console.log( a );

    /*  */
    // The following will log the number of post in this particular post
    var isImageSlider = 0;
    var postImageSlider = &quot;&quot;
        + &quot;&lt;div class='post-image-slider'&gt;&quot;
        + &quot;&lt;ul class='rslides'&gt;&quot;;

    console.log( &quot;Number of images in the post: &quot; + img.length );

    // the `img` variable is an array of images in the post, so we run a for loop to get all the images in that array
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; img.length; i++) {
      var imgSrc = img[i].src;
      console.log( &quot;Image #&quot; + i + &quot; : &quot; + imgSrc );
    }

    if ( img.length &gt; 1 ) {
      isImageSlider = 1;
      for (var i = 0; i &lt; img.length; i++) {
          var imgSrc = img[i].src;
          postImageSlider += &quot;&lt;li&gt;&lt;img src='&quot;+ imgSrc +&quot;' alt=''&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&quot;;  
      }
      postImageSlider += &quot;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&quot;;
    }



    // This simply checks in there's more than one image
    if ( img.length &gt; 1 ) {
      console.log(&quot;This post contains more than one image&quot;);
    }
    else if ( img.length &lt; 1 ) {
      console.log(&quot;This post contains no images at all&quot;);
    }
    else {
      console.log(&quot;This post contains only one image&quot;);
    }

    /* deepak's code ends here */


    ifr = p.getElementsByTagName(&quot;iframe&quot;);
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; ifr.length; i++) {
        videoUrl = ifr[i].src;
        if (videoUrl.indexOf(&quot;//www.youtube.com/embed/&quot;) != -1) {
            ifrtb = i;
            service = &quot;youtube&quot;;
        break
}
 else if (videoUrl.indexOf(&quot;//player.vimeo.com/video/&quot;) != -1) {
            ifrtb = i;
            service = &quot;vimeo&quot;;
            break
        }
 else if (videoUrl.indexOf(&quot;//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/&quot;) != -1) {
            ifrtb = i;
            service = &quot;dailymotion&quot;;
            break
        }
    }
videoId = check_id( videoUrl, service );
  if ( service == &quot;vimeo&quot; ) {
    thumbnailUrl = &quot;http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/&quot; + videoId + &quot;_.jpg&quot;;
  }
else if ( service == &quot;youtube&quot; ) {
    thumbnailUrl = &quot;http://img.youtube.com/vi/&quot;+ videoId +&quot;/maxresdefault.jpg&quot;;
  }
  else if ( service == &quot;dailymotion&quot; ) {
    thumbnailUrl = &quot;http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/&quot; + videoId;
  }


    if ( !isImageSlider ) {
        if (ifrtb != -1) ifrtag = '&lt;div class=&quot;block-image&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;thumb&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;' + y + '&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;'+ thumbnailUrl +'&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';

         else if (img.length &gt;= 1) imgtag = '&lt;div class=&quot;block-image&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;thumb&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;' + y + '&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;'+ img[0].src +'&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';

        else imgtag = '';
        p.innerHTML = ifrtag + imgtag + '';
    }

    else {
      ifrtag = '&lt;div class=&quot;block-image&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;thumb slider-images-container&quot;&gt;'+ postImageSlider +'&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';
      p.innerHTML = ifrtag + '';
    }


}

function check_id( url, service ) {
  var regExp;
  if (service == &quot;vimeo&quot;) {
    regExp = /^.*(?:vimeo.com)\/(?:channels\/|channels\/\w+\/|groups\/[^\/]*\/videos\/|albu\/\d+\/video\/|video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)/;

    var idArr = url.match( regExp );
    if ( idArr[1] &amp;&amp; parseInt(idArr[1]) ) {
      return idArr[1];
    }
    else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

else if (service == &quot;youtube&quot; ) {
var ID = '';
  url = url.replace(/(&gt;|&lt;)/gi,'').split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);
  if(url[2] !== undefined) {
    ID = url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i);
    ID = ID[0];
  }
  else {
    ID = url;
  }
    return ID;
}
  else if (service == &quot;dailymotion&quot; ) {
    var m = url.match(/^.+dailymotion.com\/(video|hub|embed)\/([^_]+)[^#]*(#video=([^_&amp;]+))?/);
    if (m !== null) {
        if(m[4] !== undefined) {
            return m[4];
        }
        return m[2];
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the ability to have a default image, replace the following code

```
else imgtag = '';
```

with

```
else imgtag = '<div class="block-image"><div class="thumb"><a href="' + y + '"><img src="'+ defaultImageURL +'"/></a></div></div>';
```

and add a variable `defaultImageURL` with the link to the default image.

To resize the images to higher resolution, replace the following code -

```
imgSrc = img[i].src
```

&

```
img[0].src
```

with the following code respectively -

```
imgSrc = img[i].src.replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s1600')
```

and

```
img[0].src.replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s1600')
```